# FlatMap run on main thread even using Scheuler.io

Tags: android, rx-java2, rx-android

I've tested and it's surely that emit value from the main thread cause this problem. However, I want to know if I have this use case to receive some value from the main thread to continue the Rx flow. what should be done in order to make flatMap run in a different thread than main.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var emitter: ObservableEmitter<String>

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        btnFlatMap.setOnClickListener {

            val obs = Observable.create<String> {
                emitter = it
                logThread("inside observable")

                // TODO: fetch some configuration from the internet or local db

                // TODO: then call startActivityForResult()
            }

            obs
                .flatMap {
                    logThread("flatMap, Banana")
                    Observable.just("$it, 1 Item")
                }
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe({ next ->
                    logThread("onNext")
                }, { error ->
                    logThread("onError")
                }, {
                    logThread("onComplete")
                })
        }

        btnEmitter.setOnClickListener {
            // TODO: simulate that onActivityResult is called
            emitter.onNext("Banana")
            emitter.onComplete()
        }
    }

    private fun logThread(operation: String) {
        Log.e("THREAD", "$operation run at [${Thread.currentThread().name}]")
    } }
```

**current Logcat**

inside observable run at [RxCachedThreadScheduler-1]

flatMap, Banana run at [main]

onNext run at [main]

onComplete run at [main]

**expected Logcat**

inside observable run at [RxCachedThreadScheduler-1]

flatMap, Banana run at [RxCachedThreadScheduler-1]

onNext run at [main]

onComplete run at [main]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add one additional `onserverOn(Schedulers.io())` does the trick, to tell Rx switch thread back to worker thread

```
        obs
            .observeOn(Schedulers.io()) <------ additional 
            .flatMap {
                logThread("flatMap, Banana")
                Observable.just("$it, 1 Item")
            }
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe({ next ->
                logThread("onNext")
            }, { error ->
                logThread("onError")
            }, {
                logThread("onComplete")
            })
```

because the data emitted from the main thread, it causes RX to switch the whole downstream from worker thread (Schedulers.io) which registered by `subscribeOn()` while a subscription to the main thread. in order to change (switch) execution thread for the whole downstream to worker thread again `observeOn()` is made for that purpose.

in short

- `observeOn`, change downstream to executing on a particular thread.
- `subscribeOn`, set the upstream (root source) to executing on a particular thread.

**Now the Logcat**

flatMap, Banana run at [RxCachedThreadScheduler-1]

onNext run at [main]

onComplete run at [main]

Comment: Can you explain your answer?

Comment: @MidasLefko regarding the question, I have tested and found the reason why `flatMap` executing on the main thread. it's because I emit the value from the main thread. so, it makes the rest of the stream using that thread. in order to switch back to the worker thread `observeOn()` is used for that purpose.

Comment: more info about observeOn vs subscribeOn https://proandroiddev.com/rx-java-subscribeon-and-observeon-a7d95041ce96

Comment: another good one https://blog.gojekengineering.com/multi-threading-like-a-boss-in-android-with-rxjava-2-b8b7cf6eb5e2